Bluetooth does not work properly on Google Workspace managed devices
We are developing an application using Bluetooth for our app, and Bluetooth connection did not work on a Chromebook (NEC PC-YAE11X21A4J2) device with restricted permissions under Google Workspace management.
The permissions enabled on the app are as follows:

ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE
INTERNET
BLUETOOTH
BLUETOOTH_ADMIN
BLUETOOTH_ADMIN - BLUETOOTH_ADVERTISE
BLUETOOTH_CONNECT
BLUETOOTH_PRIVILEGED
BLUETOOTH_SCAN
ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION
ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION

GoogleWorkspace allows the following permissions:

Location information
Bluetooth

When we checked the environment onsite, we were able to scan the device successfully, but when we tried to Connect to the device, the process did not return from there (the process was stopped).
We were able to cancel the process and no errors or exceptions were returned.
We have confirmed that it works correctly on another Android device (not under Google Workspace management).
To isolate the problem, we also checked with a Bluetooth connection meter app from another company, and it was able to scan but not connect in the same way.
The version of the device is ChromeOS 129.0.6668.110.
I would like to know what I can do to improve the above.
